# Limit points of $\{(\sin(n),\cos(m)) : n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My homework question is the prove that the set $\{(\sin(n),\cos(m)) :n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ has limit points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, this set looks finite to me, which would imply that it has no limit points. Where am I getting this wrong?

Comment: I doubt this is finite. In fact, if I had to guess, I would say the set of limit points is dense in $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$

Comment: In maths angles are in radians.

Comment: @MPW If it's dense, isn't it simply $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Yes, that's what I mean, sorry, I put it badly. The set itself is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** The set $\{\sin(n) | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is countably infinite (not finite) because the periodicity of the sine is irrational...